# How to display json data in a smarty template?

Tags: php, json, smarty, jsonresult

I'm using smarty and php for my website. There is some code which converts the data into json. I want to use that data in a smarty template. That data is a set of error messages and I want to display those messages in a assigned smarty template at desired ID. I'm not able to get that in smarty template. Actually what is happening is the error messages are displayed on a plain page instead in the desired tag.
Following is my smarty and PHP code:
Following is the smarty code where I want to display the error messages:

```
if $error_msg}<div class="error-info">{$error_msg.error_msgs}</div>{/if}
```

Now following is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if($request['form_submitted']=='yes') {
                $ret = $objPracticeSheet->InsertPracticeSheet($request, $practice_sheet_error_messages);
                if(!$ret) { 
                    $error_msg  = $objPracticeSheet->GetAllErrors();
                    $data = array();
                    $data['error_message'] = $error_msg['error_msgs'];
                    $data = json_encode($data);
                    echo $data;
                    die;
                } else {
                    $data = array();
                    $data['success_message'] = "success";
                    $data = json_encode($data);
                    echo $data;
                    die;
                }
            } else { 

                $all_subjects = $objSubjectsTopicsQues->GetAllSubjectsHavingTopics();
                $smarty->assign('all_subjects', $all_subjects);
                $smarty->assign('sheet_type', 'practice');
                $bread_crumbs_text = 'Add Practice Sheet';
                $submit_value      = 'Submit';
                $cancel_value      = 'Cancel';
                $file_to_show      = 'manage-practice-sheet.tpl';
            }
$smarty->assign("op", $op);
    $smarty->assign("query_string", $query_string);
    $smarty->assign("bread_crumbs_text", $bread_crumbs_text);
    $smarty->assign("submit_value", $submit_value);
    $smarty->assign("cancel_value", $cancel_value);
  $smarty->assign("error_msg", $error_msg);
  $smarty->assign("file_to_show", $file_to_show);
  /*$smarty->assign('create', '-active');
  $smarty->assign("sub_menu_file", "epn-create-sub-menu.tpl");
  $smarty->assign('practice_sheet', '-active');*/
  $smarty->assign('practice_sheet', 'active');
  $smarty->assign('prepare', 'selected');
  $smarty->display("index.tpl");
?>
```

Can you help me in displaying the error messages json data in the above div? Thanks in advance. I'm also attaching the screenshot of the current output.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to parse the JSON, then put the errors in the div.

To make this easier, let's give your div an `id`:

```
<div id="error-info-main" class="error-info"></div>
```

Then

```
<script>
{literal}
(function() {
    var error_json = {/literal}{$error_msg.error_msgs}{literal};
    var errors = JSON.parse(error_json);
    document.getElementById('error-info-main').innerHTML = errors.error_message;
}());
{/literal}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could just the pass the message itself from PHP:

```
$smarty->assign("error_msg", $error_msg->error_message);
```

This may not be 100% correct, as I don't have your data to test with, but I believe that's right. You get the idea at any rate.